# System log giving Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image

Tags: magento-1.7, error, product-images, log

We get a strange error in our system.log that says the following:

```
2015-06-04T07:45:25+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image::init() must be an instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Product, null given, called in /home/tablet/domains/fooss.nl/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml on line 104 and defined  in /home/tablet/domains/fooss.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php on line 139
```

this is what showon on line 104 in list.phtml

```
<div class="hovertriggerinnerimages">       
                    <div id="gallerythumbs">
                        <?php
                         $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
                         $helper = Mage::Helper('catalog/image');
                            $imgi = 0;
                            foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
                                if($imgi < 5) {
                                    echo '<a data-id="' . $_product->getId() . '" data-url="' . $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $image->getFile())->resize(157) . '" class="hoveroverimagethumb ' . $_product->getId() . '-' . $imgi . '" href="' . $_product->getProductUrl() . '" title="' . $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) .'"><img width="48" height="48" src="' . $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $image->getFile())->resize(157) . '"/></a>';
                                }
                                $imgi++;
                            }
                        ?>
                    </div>
```

Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: what's the code at line 104 from `template/catalog/product/list.phtml`? most probably a variable is null instead of a product instance.

Comment: Dear Marius, I just edited the question with the code you asked. Let me know what you think

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$this->getProduct()` returns `null`.
Usually there is no product instance associated to the list block. 
Most probably, the line you posted in the question is called in a `foreach` loop.
I think it's something like this:

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    ....
   <?php
   echo '<a data-id="' . $_product->getId() . '" data-url="' . $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $image->getFile())->resize(157) . '" class="hoveroverimagethumb ' . $_product->getId() . '-' . $imgi . '" href="' . $_product->getProductUrl() . '" title="' . $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) .'"><img width="48" height="48" src="' . $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $image->getFile())->resize(157) . '"/></a>';
   ....
   ?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

You need to replace `$this->getProduct()` with `$_product`.

Comment: Hi Marius, just placed the total div with code above. If I am correct it is already $_product, is there something you see that is wrong in that code?

Comment: Hmm...it's not what I thought. Replace `$this->getProduct()` with `$product` (so no underscore) everywhere inside your `foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {` loop

Comment: I can't see how you mean, your comment ends with loop. How do you think we could make this work?

Comment: @Coen Let me try to make it simpler...At line 104 (the one that starts with `echo`) replace all occurrences of `$this->getProduct()` with `$product`.

Comment: get it, sorry did not see the $this getproduct, will try it and let you know if everything still works!

Comment: since the moment I changed it our mobile detect gives a fatal error: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Mobile_Detect in /home2/stagingloungeset/public_html/app/code/community/Optimiseweb/MobileDetect/Library/Mobile_Detect.php on line 26. If I change  $product back to $this->getProduct() it still keeps giving the fatal error, any ideas?

Comment: I have no idea what Mobile_Detect is . It's not from the core.